Unable to import json file to Azure Devops libray with expressions
How can I import json file to Azure DevOps Library Variable Group where the variable name and value contains expressions such as $() or $[].
This is the script that I am using to import the json files.
$jsonFilesDirectory = "C:\variables" 
$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $jsonFilesDirectory -Filter *.json 
foreach ($json in $jsonFiles) 
{ $jsonnames = $json.Name 
$jsonContent = Get-Content -Path "C:\variables\$jsonnames" | Out-String 

    $variableGroup = $jsonContent | ConvertFrom-Json

    $groupName = $variableGroup.name
    $description = $variableGroup.description
    $variablesObject = $variableGroup.variables
    
    $variablesHashtable = @{}
    foreach ($property in $variablesObject.PSObject.Properties) {
        $variableName = $property.Name
        $variableValue = $property.Value.value
        $variablesHashtable[$variableName] = $variableValue
    }
    $variablesString = $variablesHashtable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" } 
    
    # Create variable group using Azure CLI
    az pipelines variable-group create --name $groupName --variables $variablesString --description $description --detect false --org 'https://dev.azure.com/<org>' --project '<project>'

}

I receive the following error.
az : --description was unexpected at this time.
At line:22 char:5
+     az pipelines variable-group create --name $groupName --variables  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (--description w...d at this time.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
C:\Users\******>  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\\..\python.exe" -IBm azure.cli pipelines variable-group create --name "Test Variable" --variables BusinessRulesAssemblyLocalStoragePath=test-$(env) --description "Test upload" --detect false --org https://dev.azure.com/****** --project "*******"

This is the json file.
{
  "authorized": false,
  "description": "Test upload",
  "name": "Test",
  "project": "****",
  "type": "Vsts",
  "variables": {
    "TestVariable": {
      "isSecret": false,
      "value": "test-$(env)"
    }
  }
}

It works if I remove the expresson.

$(env)


What is the error message you are getting after script execution. @albbla91

Hi @Jahnavi, the error was too long to add as a comment. I added it on the question

Based on my test, it seems that az CLI doesn't support $(). As a workaround, you can use REST API Variablegroups - Add to create variable group.
Add variableGroupProjectReferences to your Json file. Replace the name inside projectReference with your project name. For example,
{
  "authorized": false,
  "description": "Test upload",
  "name": "Test",
  "type": "Vsts",
  "variables": {
    "BusinessRulesAssemblyLocalStoragePath": {
      "isSecret": false,
      "value": "test-$(env)"
    }
  },
  "variableGroupProjectReferences": [
        {
            "projectReference": {
                "name": "{project name}"
            },
            "name": "Test",
            "description": "Test upload"
        }
    ]
}

Then run the following PowerShell scripts:
$jsonFilesDirectory = "C:\variables" 
$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $jsonFilesDirectory -Filter *.json 
foreach ($json in $jsonFiles) 
{ $jsonnames = $json.Name 
  $jsonContent = Get-Content -Path "C:\variables\$jsonnames" | Out-String 
  $organization = "{Organization name}"
  $token = "{PAT}"
  $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
  $url="https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
  $head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $jsonContent -ContentType application/json

}


Hi @Ziyang Liu-MSFT, it works by using the Rest Api. Thank you for your help.
